# "These" with uncountable nouns

Tags: plural-forms, uncountable-nouns

I know that "These" can only be followed by plural nouns.
ex: These flowers are beautiful.

My questions are:

1. Can I use multiple uncountable nouns after "These"?
   ex: These milk, butter, and bread are beyond their sell-by dates.
2. Can I mention uncountable nouns together with countable ones after "These"?
   ex: These evidence and witnesses prove him guilty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using demonstrative adjectives with a list, you should use one for each item in the list.  See more on "demonstrative adjectives" [on this page](http://data.grammarbook.com/blog/adjectives-adverbs/thisthatthesethose-demonstrative-adjectives/).

> **This** milk, **this** butter, and **this** bread are beyond their sell-by dates.

Even though those nouns are uncountable, you use "this" and not "these," because uncountable nouns are generally treated as singular.  [See here for more information on that subject.](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/nouns-countable-un.htm)

In your second example, one item is singular (uncountable and treated as singular) and one is plural, so you would use different demonstrative adjectives for each:

> **This** evidence and **these** witnesses prove him guilty.

Using a demonstrative adjective is only necessary to point to *which* objects you're talking about.  In most cases, you could avoid this problem by simply using an article like "the."

> **The** milk, butter, and bread are beyond their sell-by dates.
>   **The** evidence and witnesses prove him guilty.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think people would say or write this. I would expect something like:

> These **things**, *the* milk, butter, and bread are beyond their sell-by dates.

Your other example might simply be:

> These **points**, *the* evidence and witnesses prove him guilty.